# ng-selected not working in select element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a bound select

```
<select ng-model="collegeSelection" ng-options="c as c.CollegeName for c in colleges" ng-selected="c.CollegeName == collegeSelection.CollegeName" name="selectCollege" id="selectCollege"></select>
```

but when both c.CollegeName == collegeSelection.CollegeName match the item still isn't selected. Documentation doesn't seem to help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`ng-selected` should be used in the `<option>` tag, not in the `<select>` tag. Take a closer look at its [doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSelected) and the example.

Because the `select` directive's determination of the selected option is based on `ngModel`. Therefore, once you remove `ng-selected="c.CollegeName == collegeSelection.CollegeName"`, your code should work.

I created a very simple [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/cmAe0QWODQys1PQYaKGv) to demonstrate the "selected" feature in `select` directive.

### More details:

AngularJS uses `ngModel` directive to enable "two-way data binding" between your model and UI elements.

In the case of "select", the model `collegeSelection` you specified as `<select ng-model="collegeSelection" ...>` is the *selected* item. Which means if an user selects an item from the dropdown on the page, `collegeSelection` will be set to that item; **and**, if you set `collegeSelection` to an item in your javascript code, AngularJS will make sure that the corresponded `<option>` is selected.

Say you have the following code in your controller:

```
$scope.colleges = [
    {id: 0, name: 'a'},
    {id: 1, name: 'b'},
    {id: 2, name: 'c'}
];

$scope.collegeSelection = $scope.colleges[0];
```

And the HTML looks like:

```
<select ng-model="collegeSelection" ng-options="c as c.name for c in colleges"></select>
```

That's it! The first college in the colleges array *will be selected* if you run the code.

Just remember `collegeSelection` **is** the selected option, no matter it's because user selected an item on the UI, or you selected an item in javascript.

That's how two-way data binding works.

Comment: I see, but what I'm trying to do is make a certain item within the select element the selected element. How would one do that?

Comment: You just need to set the `collegeSelection` model.

Answer (score 12):

After playing around with `ng-selected` for a while I was not able to get it to work like you're asking. However, I was able to pre-select a specific option using `ng-init`.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/g2MhM/) of my solution. My `<select>` ended up being:

```
 <select ng-model="selectedColor" ng-options="color.value as color.name for color in colors" ng-init="selectedColor='yellow'">
   <option value="">Select A Color</option>
 </select>`
```

And my `colors` array is:

```
 colors = [
        {name:'Red', value: 'red'}, 
        {name:'Orange', value: 'orange'}, 
        {name:'Yellow', value: 'yellow'}, 
        {name:'Green', value: 'green'}, 
        {name:'Blue', value: 'blue'}, 
        {name:'Indigo', value: 'indigo'}, 
        {name:'Violet', value: 'violet'}
 ]
```

Changing the `ng-init="selectedColor='yellow'"` to another value will select a different option.

Comment: You don't necessarily need `ngInit`. Try to add `$scope.selectedColor = 'yellow';` after your `$scope.colors = [...];`

Answer (score 1):

Some people have problems with this. I found a great solution for a simple drop down if `controller as someController`

```
var vm = this;
this.colors = [
        {name:'Red'}, 
        {name:'Orange'}, 
        {name:'Yellow'}, 
        {name:'Green'}, 
        {name:'Blue'}, 
        {name:'Indigo'}, 
        {name:'Violet'}
 ];
this.color_selected = "Yellow";
<select ng-model="someController.color_selected" ng-options="opt.name as opt.name for opt in someController.colors">
</select>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and realized the cause was because of the different data types. `ng-model` was comparing against a string value but I was pulling an integer from the database so it wasn't automatically selecting the option. To overcome this, i called `toString()` on the integer after querying the data from the database to ensure the data types matched.