# How to select option in Angular by key?

Tags: angularjs

I have the followinf Angular JS code:

```
 <select ng-model="formData.beginDay[$index]" class=form-control" ng-required="!formData.current[$index]">
                            <option ng-repeat="day in data.dateList.day" value="{{day.id}}" ng-selected="day.id == '0'">
                                {{day.value}}
                            </option>
                        </select>
```

The object `data.dateList` looks as:

```
0: {id: 0, value: "G"}
id: 0
value: "G"
```

I set attribute `ng-selected`:

```
ng-selected="day.id == '0'"
```

But It does not select first element in select list.

Comment: Your question is answered here: [ng-selected not working in select element](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17646636/5535245)

Comment: I tried this solution, it did not help me

Comment: Can you provide us with a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show us your problem?