# How do I pre-select the selected item in a dropdown list? [Angular]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently have a service in angular returning me a list of states. The array looks like this:

```
model.Address.StateList = [
     { Disabled: false,
       Group: null,
       Selected: false,
       Text: "CA",
       Value: "1"
      },
 { Disabled: false,
       Group: null,
       Selected: false,
       Text: "IL",
       Value: "2"
      },
      { Disabled: false,
       Group: null,
       Selected: false,
       Text: "NJ",
       Value: "3"
      }
]
```

I am also returning from the service the state they actually choose which looks like this:

```
 model.Address.State = "CA"
```

I have scoured stackoverflow trying to find a way to make this work but I can't figure out how to pre-select the value in the list.

I have tried this:

```
<select id="State" ng-model="model.Address.State" ng-change="changeState(model.Address.State)" ng-options="option as option.Text for option in model.Address.StateList track by option.Value"></select>
```

But that does not pre-select the first item.

The one way I have got it to work is changing ng-model to "selectedItem" and in the controller I wrote:

```
   $scope.selectedItem = responseModel.Address.StateList[0];
```

But that only picks the first item.

It seems that the problem is that I have a collection of States but the model I want is just the singular text. And ideally I'd like to set the selected to be added to the model object so when I save I can just pass "model" to my api with all the values I need.

Comment: Are you using a form?

Comment: Not at this moment, no

Comment: Have you seen these answers?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968760/how-to-set-a-selected-option-of-a-dropdown-list-control-using-angular-js

Comment: @georgeawg your link is to $http but I did check  out [the resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) before posting

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17646636/5535245) will help.

Answer (score 1):

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pw7a6tyb/2/) for a possible solution.

I am using a scope variable `selectedState` there and use it in the `ng-model` attribute, but you can replace that with `model.Address.State` if you prefer.

---

Since you bind `model.Address.State` with the `ngModel` directive and use `track by option.Value`, you can set the value of `model.Address.State` to the value of the option that you want to set active:

```
model.Address.State = "1";
```

If you want to use `"CA"` instead, you can change your `ng-model` to a property of the current scope:

```
<select ng-model="model.Address.State" ng-options="option.Text as option.Text for ... track by Text" ...>

$scope.selectedState = "CA";
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me. I have tried both yours and @foxdonut without luck. I can't seem to get model.Address.State, which is "CA", become the selected value. And when I look at State on change of selected, the value becomes the object

Comment: I have created a jsfiddle that demonstrates the behavior you intended: http://jsfiddle.net/pw7a6tyb/1/

Answer (score 1):

The value that you want to use for `ng-model` should match the value that you use in `ng-options`. For example:

```
model.Address.State = "CA"; // matches the Text property
<select id="State" ng-model="model.Address.State" ng-options="option.Text for option in model.Address.StateList"></select>
```

If instead you want to use `Value`, you need to match them up:

```
model.Address.State = "1"; // matches the Value property
<select id="State" ng-model="model.Address.State" ng-options="option.Text as option.Value for option in model.Address.StateList"></select>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working for me at all. I have this 
       <select id="State" ng-model="model.Address.State" ng-change="test()" ng-options="option.Text for option in model.Address.StateList"></select> but and model.Address.State when being loaded in is "CA" but nothing is selected. In that ng-change function, I see that model.Address.State is equal to the whole model in State List. Meaning, if I choose IL then model.Address.State equals StateList[1] completely

Comment: Just needed `option.Text as option.Text` in my first answer and that is exactly what worked... I wouldn't say this wasn't helpful at all =P

Comment: I misspoke by saying it wasn't working for me "at all". Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

Thanks to the insightful guide written [HERE](http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/08/11/a-brief-walk-through-of-the-ng-options-in-angularjs/) I was able to understand a little more about ng-options and Select in angular.

What ended up being the problem is that I need to specify that the text shown in the dropdown list matches the text in the model. The final code that made it work was:

```
 <select id="State" ng-model="model.Address.State" ng-options="option.Text as option.Text for option in model.Address.StateList"></select>
```

Comment: this is the same as my first answer, just needed `option.Text as option.Text` was close! :)