# Setting default value in select dropdown using objects in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need some help. I can't create `$scope.headline.category` into an object, it has to stay a string. The `groupList` has to be a list of objects. How can I set the initial value of the dropdown to the 2nd item (1 index)?  I can set it through the controller but I have a lot of items and it seems like there should be an easier way... maybe using `ng-init`? Thank you for any help.

What I tried but doesn't work:

```
ng-init="headline.category = group.label"
```

What I tried that does work, but i feel like there's an easier way?

```
  for (var a = 0; a < $scope.headlineList.length; a++) {
    for (var b = 0; b < $scope.groupList.length; b++) {
        if ($scope.headlineList[a].category == $scope.groupList[b].label) {
            $scope.headlineList[a].category = $scope.groupList[b];
        }
    }
}
```

Angular

```
$scope.headline.category = "B";
$scope.groupList = [ {label: "A"}, {label: "B"}, {label: "C"} ];
```

HTML

```
<select ng-model="headline.category" ng-options="group.label for group in groupList"></select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only need the following in the controller:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope){
      $scope.headline = { category: "B" }
      $scope.groupList = [ {label: "A"}, {label: "B"}, {label: "C"} ];
  });
```

And the select changed to:

```
<select ng-model="headline.category" ng-options="group.label as group.label for group in groupList"></select>
```

The key changes being setting headline to the object of `{ category: "B" }` (set this way from some kind of ajax call I'm guessing) and the `group.label as` at the beginning of the options to indicate the value from the category objects to apply to the model.

[Plunk example](http://plnkr.co/edit/8hCeff?p=preview)

Comment: oh crap it worked!  just adding the "group.label as group.label" made it work!  ty so much

Comment: @user1189352 Also useful for saving an Id vs the label string when your lookup values are ID-Description pairings.  "group.id as group.label" in that case.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**
Try:

```
<select ng-model="headline.category" ng-init="headline.category = groupList[index]" ng-options="group.label for group in groupList"></select>
```

Contoller:

```
angular.forEach($scope.groupList, function(value, key) {
      if(value.label == $scope.headline.category){
          $scope.index = key;  
      }
  });
```

[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/R0SPaa6g1hocB4APROaQ?p=preview) with a demo.

Comment: that does work, but maybe i didn't explain the OP well enough.i need something where the initial index will be set dynamically.. i dont know if the category will be "A", "B", or "C" so i can't just set it like that unfortunately

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645620/ng-selected-not-working-in-select-element/17646636#17646636) will help. It shows how to set the initial value from the controller

Comment: @georgeawg checked it out, i guess that's what i'm doing already in the OP "What I tried that does work, but i feel like there's an easier way?".  Figured there'd be something easier but i guess not.