# set selected value in ng-option based on ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="entity in displayedProjectRoles">
    <div>
        <strong>Role: </strong> 
        <select
            ng-model="project.role" 
            ng-options="option as option.name for option in project_role"
            ng-required="true"
            id="project_role"
            class="form-control">
        </select>
    </div>
</li>
```

How can I set the value of model `project.role` based on the value on `entity.role` in the `ng-repeat`? I tried `ng-selected` or even using `entity.role` in the `ng-model` but it's not working properly.

this is the data in displayed Project Roles

```
[
  {
    "empid": 2,
    "role": "employee"
  },
  {
    "empid": 1,
    "role": "pm"
  }
]
```

and in the project_role

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "employee"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "pm"
  }
]
```

So basically the value of role in displayedProjectRoles matches with the name in project_role

Comment: given the array inputs

Comment: Try setting project.role = { "id": 1, "name": "employee" } as a test and see if it binds

Comment: What is project_role? please try to include everything. Consider building a plunker, it would be great for understanding and giving you a working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645620/ng-selected-not-working-in-select-element) is a good example of angular select.

Essentially the `ng-model` for the select has to match the `ng-option` value to bind. In your example `project.role` would have to be exactly equal to `option` from your `ng-options`. Note this is type specific so had it been

```
option.id as option.name for option in project_role
```

and `option.id == 1` then `project.role == '1'` will not bind