# ng-model with association on select box with ng-repeat on options

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a [Plunker here illustrating my issue](http://plnkr.co/edit/rhfhuAwB1eV1q1RvbZlr?p=preview). I have an object with an associated `division`. There is no `division_id` on the object, but in order to set or update the `division` I need to set the `division_id` field. Here's the sample object:

```
$scope.user = {
  name: "John",
  age: 32,
  division: {
    id: 3,
    name: "Alpha"
  }
};
```

And the example divisions:

```
$scope.divisions = [
  {
    name: "Gamma",
    id: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Alpha",
    id: 3
  },
  {
    name: "Beta",
    id: 5
  }
];
```

The way I'm building the select box is with `ng-repeat`, which I was hoping would bypass the need to track ng-model for the selected value.

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Division</label>
      <select type="text" ng-model="user.division_id">
        <option ng-repeat="division in divisions"
          ng-selected="user.division.id == division.id">{{ division.name }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

As you can see in the demo, the `selected` attribute is being placed on the right option, but still the select box display is blank. Even if I add `division_id: 3` to the object, it continues to be blank. How can I get this to work without having to do a conversion on the object when loading and updating?

**Edit:** To address this question being flagged as a duplicate, I think this is unique because I'm asking how to build the select box with `ng-repeat`, not `ng-options`. Though the answer is similar to the answer for the proposed duplicate, I think other people might get stuck on this method and find it helpful to see the answer requires a different technique.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-selected not working in select element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645620/ng-selected-not-working-in-select-element)

Comment: Why can't you just bind to `ng-model="user.division"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you update your select as follows it will display by default to the users division.id.

```
<select ng-model="user.division" ng-options="d as d.name for d in divisions track by d.id">
```

You seemed to be wanting to have a separate model `division_id`, the only reason I can think of for this is that you wanted to control the persistence of the `user` model when the selection is updated. If for some reason you want to intercept the end-users selection to the user model (or even just the in-memory user object) being updated then use a copy/there are many ways to do that, but it's not clear if that's what you're asking.

[Updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XkI5AHB5M4Y3qEPCHuet?p=preview)

Note it would have worked to have kept the same option `ng-repeat` syntax, but this is the recommended angular way to deal with options.

Comment: The problem is that `user.division.name` should also update.

Comment: So then just use `ng-model="user.division"` and use `ng-options="d as d.name for d in divisions track by d.id"`. I've updated above.

Comment: Yes, what I said 30 mins ago. I would also suggest this as a solution.

Comment: "but still the select box display is blank." @dfsq You were fast, correct, smarter than me, but not complete :), this solution removes the initial 4th blank option.

Comment: Of course there will be blank option (no need to remove it). One would just need to set correct model. http://plnkr.co/edit/nKprznI4KgjAmhpmfW63?p=preview

Comment: The `ng-options` syntax always trips me up. I tried changing the plunkr back to the option with `ng-repeat` format, using `user.division` as the `ng-model` attribute, but it didn't seem to work. Is still there something I'm missing or is `ng-options` really the only way to go with this? http://plnkr.co/edit/FUvE64ZhL30wrwmk53YF?p=preview

Comment: I think *not using* that syntax is tripping you up! Me too.. can't see a way to get what you want using the `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 0):

As per your plunker, you need to remove the ng-model directive from the select tag for it to work.

if you need to set a division_id variable for your code, you can use ng-init.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Division</label>
    <select type="text">
       <option ng-repeat="division in divisions"
          ng-selected="user.division.id == division.id"
          ng-init="division_id=division.name">{{ division.name }}
       </option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: By removing the model, the user.division will never be updated. `ng-init` is not recommended.